# in STS, referring other my own simple maven project is not working, what I am missing?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, compilation, reference, project

I am having a very simple problem, I have one spring boot starter project having only one class & I am referring it in another spring boot starter project, but getting error as :

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.590 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-13T10:25:21-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo1: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/kedarmoghe/Documents/workspaces/travel/demo1/src/main/java/com/example1/demo/AddressProcessor.java:[3,24] package com.example.demo does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/kedarmoghe/Documents/workspaces/travel/demo1/src/main/java/com/example1/demo/AddressProcessor.java:[7,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Address
[ERROR]   location: class com.example1.demo.AddressProcessor
[ERROR] /Users/kedarmoghe/Documents/workspaces/travel/demo1/src/main/java/com/example1/demo/AddressProcessor.java:[7,31] cannot find symbol
```

My pom.xml from project 1 is :

```
enter code here

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
enter code here
```

My pom.xml in project-2 is :

```
enter code here

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example1</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

enter code here
```

In my STS I am not able to compile, what step I am missing ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Projects that are packaged via the Spring Boot Maven Plugin are not naturally fit to be used as dependencies.

You can follow any of these references to edit project1's pom.xml as necessary to deploy an artifact JAR that can actually be used as a dependency, and then import that in project2:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-dependency
- https://medium.com/xebia-france/import-spring-boot-application-as-a-maven-dependency-a25e03e5c3a

Comment: Thanks Domenico. I will follow above, yes through my normal maven project it was working & spring-boot is having problem, so thought of checking if I am missing something. It helps, thanks again.